# KVC NSKeyValueChangeRemoval Not Being Observed

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to observe a collection notes. Here is the code:

```
-(void) registerNotesHeaderViewChangeNotification
{
    [self.selectedVegetableGarden addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"notes" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueChangeRemoval context:nil];
}

-(void) observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    MyVegetableGarden *vegGarden = (MyVegetableGarden *) object;

    if([vegGarden.notes count] > 0)
    {
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = [self createSharingView];
    }

    else
    {
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = nil; 
    }

}
```

Now, I want that when I remove an object from the notes collection it should fire the observeValueForKeyPath method.

```
[self.selectedVegetableGarden.notes removeObject:note];
```

Currently, it is not firing!

Comment: `NSKeyValueChange` is not a valid value for this method.  Is it working for add operations?

Comment: Not working for add either!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSKeyValueChangeRemoval` is not an option that can be passed in the `options` parameter of `-addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context:`. It's one of the values that can be in the `NSKeyValueChangeKindKey` entry of the change dictionary that's passed to your `-observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:` method.

You are not modifying the `notes` property in a KVO-compliant manner. You are obtaining the pointer to the (presumably) mutable collection via the `notes` property, but then you are directly mutating it. You should implement and then use the appropriate [collection mutation accessors](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/AccessorConventions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002174-178830-BAJEDEFB).

You could also use the `-mutableArrayValueForKey:` or `-mutableSetValueForKey:` methods to obtain a proxy and mutate the property via that proxy, which will generate the proper KVO change notification.